# Calling macros within \newsavebox

Tags: macros

Can someone explain to me how I can include the `\begin{lrbox}` in the loop? My problem is that I do not know how to call the macro `\PMOne` or `\PMTwo` within the `lrbox` environment. A Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\foreach [count=\xi] \x in {One,Two} {
    \expandafter\newsavebox\csname PM\x \endcsname
        }
%
%
\begin{lrbox}{\PMOne}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,0.5) node [right] {+1};
\draw (1,-0.5) node [right] {-1};
\draw[-] (0,0) -- node [above] {$+.5$} (1,0.5);
\draw[-] (0,0) -- node [below] {$-.5$} (1,-0.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}
%
\begin{lrbox}{\PMTwo}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,0.5) node [right] {+2};
\draw (1,-0.5) node [right] {-2};
\draw[-] (0,0) -- node [above] {$.5$} (1,0.5);
\draw[-] (0,0) -- node [below] {$.5$} (1,-0.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}
%
\begin{document}
\foreach [count=\xi] \x in {One,Two} {% 
\expandafter\usebox\csname PM\x\endcsname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean the loop over `\usebox`? `\foreach [count=\xi] \x in {One,Two} {%
\expandafter\usebox\csname PM\x\endcsname}` perhaps?

Comment: I don't think you wan't to have the `\begin{lrbox}` ... in the loop?

Comment: Sorry, I do mean the `\begin{lrbox}` loop since I will need \PMOne tow \PMTen. Thanks!

Comment: It's very unclear what loop you're referring to.

Comment: I want to define lrboxes \PMOne to \PMTen without typing `\begin{lrbox}` ten times

Comment: @Sebastian: Have a look on my suggestion, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if a `lrbox` is the right box type for usage within a `foreach` loop. I changed it to an ordinary `\hbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\foreach [count=\xi] \x in {One,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six,Seven,Eight,Nine,Ten} {
  \expandafter\newbox\csname PM\x\endcsname
  \global\setbox\csname PM\x\endcsname=\hbox{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (1,0.5) node [right] {+\xi};
      \draw (1,-0.5) node [right] {-\xi};
      \draw[-] (0,0) -- node [above] {$+.5$} (1,0.5);
      \draw[-] (0,0) -- node [below] {$-.5$} (1,-0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
}


\begin{document}

\foreach [count=\xi] \x in {One,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six,Seven,Eight,Nine,Ten} {%
  \expandafter\usebox\csname PM\x\endcsname
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is always the same: `\foreach` executes each step in the cycle inside a group, so an assignment such as `\begin{lrbox}{\PMOne}...\end{lrbox}` disappears.

You can define a global version of `lrbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newenvironment{glrbox}[1]
 {\def\thisbox{#1}\begin{lrbox}{0}}
 {\end{lrbox}\global\setbox\thisbox=\box0\relax}

\foreach [count=\xi] \x in {One,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six,Seven,Eight,Nine,Ten}
  {
   \expandafter\newsavebox\csname PM\x\endcsname
   \begin{glrbox}{\csname PM\x\endcsname}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw (1,0.5) node [right] {$+\xi$};
     \draw (1,-0.5) node [right] {$-\xi$};
     \draw[-] (0,0) -- node [above] {$+.5$} (1,0.5);
     \draw[-] (0,0) -- node [below] {$-.5$} (1,-0.5);
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{glrbox}
  }


\begin{document}

\foreach [count=\xi] \x in {One,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six,Seven,Eight,Nine,Ten}
 {%
  \expandafter\usebox\csname PM\x\endcsname\par
 }
\end{document}
```