# Filling Text with Pattern

Tags: pattern

Text can be colored:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
{\textcolor{green}{\Large I}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Areas can be filled with `patterns`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=bricks, pattern color=green] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: patterned square]

How could you fill letters or symbols with a `pattern`?

For example, an "I" filled with green bricks would look something like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% shouldn't need to trace a symbol!
\draw[pattern=bricks, pattern color=green] (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,1) -- (2,1) -- (2,3) -- (3,3) -- (3,4) -- (0, 4) -- (0,3) -- (1,3) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58851/convert-font-letters-to-vector-format-and-fill-with-a-pattern

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually this is very similar to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192528/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns}
\begin{document} 
\newcommand\textpattern[2][pattern=bricks]{%
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=letter]
\node [text=transparent!0,scale=10,font=\bfseries\sffamily] {#2};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [opacity=0,scale=10,font=\bfseries\sffamily] (aux) {#2};
\path[path fading=letter,fit fading=false,#1]
    (aux.south west) rectangle (aux.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\textpattern{Hello}

\textpattern[pattern=bricks,pattern color=green]{world!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I want to make sure I understand your method. You create a fading that is transparent except over the text. Then you  make a node with the same text which you later use to size the rectangle you draw along the faded path. The patterns that are drawn in the rectangle come from #1 and the text comes from #2. Is this correct?

Comment: @anonymous_pigeon Yes, more or less. `#1` are keys that control the pattern, and the default is `pattern=bricks`. `#2` is the text, as you say. There are many ways in which you could write the command, and one may use pgf keys to make it more flexible.

Comment: @anonymous_pigeon BTW, it is not too difficult to add the contour to the characters. You essentially need to add the tricks that are used [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439471/121799). (The more original posts are linked there.)